# First Raspberry Pi 4 setup using a USB memory via Ethernet

Tags: raspbian, usb, ethernet

It is my first time Raspberry Pi use, I prepared the Raspbian OS on a USB memory, using Ethernet connection shared from a laptop, but it always failed by pinging or via putty.
I tried with both: static and dynamic ip addresses following those tutorials :
[video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrvB0VVMynM&t=560s)
[2nd tutorial](https://matwick.ca/raspi-ics/)

is the problem related to the first use using USB v2.0 memory (64Gb), is it necessary to setup just with SD card ?

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what "on a flash disc memory" or "is the problem related to the first use using USB v2.0 memory" means or what you have done. Try installing Raspberry Pi OS using the standard methods https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/

Comment: please excuse my english expression. I do not have a keyboard neither a SD card to follow the standard methods, just a laptop, so I followed the tutorials to copy the os in a usb memory and connect the raspberry to laptop via ethernet cable and HDMI cable

Answer (score 1):

"I do not have a keyboard neither a SD card to follow the standard methods"

You do not need either (although this makes the process more difficult).

You can use any storage; SD Card is preferred, but you can use a USB Flash drive.

To enable `ssh` you need to edit the boot drive. If you use the latest Raspberry Pi Imager there are advanced options, invoked by the magic key sequence: Ctrl-Shift-X. These enable you to set many initial options; hostname, password, ssh, WiFi Country Code etc during imaging. This should enable you to setup a headless system, without the need to edit any files.

"and connect the raspberry to laptop via ethernet cable and HDMI cable"

It is unclear what you have done; it is POSSIBLE to use an Ethernet cable, but this only gives limited `ssh` access. It is preferable to connect to your router, either by Ethernet or WiFi.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Connecting a HDMI cable to the laptop will do nothing (except possibly damage either HDMI port) as these are output only.

---

Edit Now that you have indicated "using Ethernet connection shared from a laptop" you should know that you can have **either** ICS **OR** internet access, not both. Without a keyboard etc it is useless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't knew that the imager gives us more options i will recopy the os. But can we use Wifi for first use without os installation yet ? I can't connect ethernet cable to router for now it's far from me.

Comment: @HindDev If you set advanced options, including WiFi Country Code and network details it is possible. I don't know why they choose to hide this option.

Comment: I tried every option, even thouse in the documentation you gave me, I can't access it. I'm thinnking about win 10 that I am accessing with, can it bloc the access ?

Comment: I haven't used Windows in a decade so can't comment. "tried every option" is not helpful. The advanced options assume you know what to specify; you need to be more specific.

Comment: I find the sollution, I had to make eeprom updated before, using the os on a SD card and upgrade it so it could be able to boot from usb memory. thanks